# Matrix represented as blocks - Maple - Cellular automaton

Tags: matrix, maple, automaton

I only have very basic Maple skills and unsure how to represent a matrix as graphically as blocks, where 1 in the matrix corresponds to a block and a 0 corresponds to an empty space.

Please see my code below where I am adding a "1" i.e. a block to the central column in a loop.  I was wondering whether this is any way this could be animated in maple, with the "1"s as solid squares.  [image]

This is a picture of what someone achieved with a different software.
Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

```
restart;
with(LinearAlgebra):
with(MTM);
with(RandomTools);


M := Matrix([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]);


for a to 4 do if (sum(M, 1))[3] < 5 
then z := max(ListTools[SearchAll](0, M..., 3))); 
M(z, 3) := M(z, 3)+1 
end if; 
print(M):
end do;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the Maple command `plots:-sparsematrixplot` will get you most of the way there.  An sequence of such plots could be animated with the plots:-display command and its `insequence` option.  For example, 10 random matrices:

```
L := NULL;
to 10 do
    L := L, plots:-sparsematrixplot(LinearAlgebra:-RandomMatrix(6, 6, generator = 0 .. 1));
end do;

plots:-display(L, insequence)
```

Comment: Thanks, the sparsematrixplot command works well! I have tried to create an array of matrices from this but have been unsuccessful.  Would you be able to tell me how to do this please?

Comment: I should have said "sequence" instead of "array".  I've added an example.